# Shivv or PD on vayne?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know pd better for the late game but in team fights, which item is better on vayne , Shivv or Phantom dancer and why? ( I started to play adc again )

Comment: Either - PD or shiv is really an opinion based choice

Comment: depends on your teamcombo too. i preffer shiv if my team lacks waveclear

Comment: Shiv is better since the damage spike provided by its passive,  also it's slightly better in terms of movement speed,  and cheaper.

Comment: This Q&A might be helpful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/180058/when-is-statikk-shiv-better-than-phantom-dancer/180174#180174

Comment: The real question should be PH or Yommuu's. To which the answer is: If the team has considerable cc, go PH, if not go Yomuu's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both items are quite equal on most ADC, not just Vayne.
The difference between the two is that Phantom Dancer gives you better base stats, while Statik Shivv has the charge-up chain-lightning passive. This means that Phantom Dancer will give you better sustained damage, while Statik Shivv will give a greater initial burst.

Your choice for which to get may vary game to game, and there are many reasons why one could be more beneficial than another.

For example, if the enemy team is mostly tanky, it may be better to get a Phantom Dancer, since you won't be 1 bursting any of them down, and you'll prefer the larger sustained damage to kill all of them.

If you're looking at duelling mid-game by surprising squishy enemies, perhaps Statik Shivv may be a better choice in that case. There is also nothing stopping you from getting both items in 1 game (although arguably there are much better items to complete first after getting one of these).

Statik Shivv is also better on champs that will move around a lot, since it'll ready the passive faster (Lucian, for example)

Comment: tumble (vayne Q) also makes the passive charge faster

Comment: The passive on statikk shiv can also crit, making it a more viable rush together with Infinity Edge. (Not the standard Vayne build, which is: BOTRK rush). Also keep in mind that the passive is magic damage, which actually makes it more viable to build against tanky comps.

Answer (score 1):

Logically thinking, it really depends on your current/target AD and ASpd.

- If your Vayne is inclined to hitting harder(Having a higher AD or planning to use Infinity Edge after) then you should take Phantom Dancer since the crit chance is much higher, and it gives you faster mobility and attack speed. This maximizes the Damage output.
- If your Vayne is more of an ASpd build(maximizing the Silver Bolts), then you should take the Statikk Shiv since it will proc the passive more.

Comment: You think BT ( bloodthirster) would only work with PD ? I concentrate on getting off as much as 3 proc autos for silver bolts which is why I max it out first , I did hear however, Koreans only go BT + PD If maxing q , Would you agree?

Comment: Yes I do agree with the Koreans doing that, since BT is an AD inclined item and Vayne's tumble, scale with AD.

Answer (score 1):

They're similar enough in power that choosing one over the other probably won't affect your damage too much. However, depending on what your goals are in game, you might prefer Stativ Shiv or Phantom Dancer. For example, Statik Shiv would probably be an excellent choice for split pushing whereas Phantom Dancer would be a bit stronger for dueling 1v1.

Answer (score 0):

With Vayne, PD is my 100% buy every single time. As her early game is worse than an underfed Kha'Zix, buying SS is a very quirky way to build Vayne. Sure, you get more burst, but you need the AS to pop 3 stacks quicker. Especially when your W is maxed, your true damage of 8 PERCENT OF THE TARGET'S MAX HEALTH will bowl heads compared to the maximum of 250 it can do on a target before having to AA around 9 times to get that 100~250 damage.